# Parse local JSON file with jQuery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse a JSON file located on my computer. I want to parse it. The JSON file has this structure:

```
{
  "sites": {
    "site": [
      {
        "id": "01",
        "name": "Sito 1",
        "src": "localhost/root/coupon/sito1",
        "expiryDate": "29 Ago 2013"
      },
      {
        "id": "02",
        "name": "Sito 2",
        "src": "localhost/root/coupon/sito2",
        "expiryDate": "30 Ago 2013"
      },
      {
        "id": "Sito 3",
        "name": "Sito 3",
        "src": "localhost/root/coupon/sito2",
        "expiryDate": "31 Ago 2013"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In my html I import the jQuery library and I made a function that will load when the page is loaded. The code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>  
        <title>Lista coupon</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            function loadJson() {
                window.alert("Carico il contenuto del file JSON per popolare la lista");
                $(document).ready(function()
                    {
                        $.getJSON('data.json', function(json) {
                            console.log(json);
                        });
                    });
                }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="loadJson();">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Lista coupon salvati</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <p>Di seguito trovi tutte le promozioni salvate</p>

        </div>
        <div id="footer">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I saw on firebug console that it can read correctly the JSON file, but I don't know how to parse this JSON. I searched in google, but I found a lot of example that use a remote JSON. Can you help me to understand how to parse a local JSON file?
Thank you

PS: note the site I post on here it's made for mobile browser.

Comment: getJson makes a HTTP call to the **server** not to your computer. Read the documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: do a console.log on the 'obj'-variable and check how it's built. Will make you understand how you should use it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`getJSON` will parse it for you.

Just remove the `var obj = $.parseJSON(json);` line (since that will stringify the object and try to parse it as JSON (which it won't be)).

Comment: Ok i removed it, but now how I can access to the object? Now I want to "capture" the entry "name" and "src"

Comment: `json` is the object. Access it like any other. (`json.sites.etc`)

Comment: so I've to do simply json.name and json.src to get the name and the link? I tried it with an alert, but it says me undefined...

Comment: No, since `name` and `src` are not properties of the object stored in `json`. You have to drill down the hierarchy. You might want to read [Objects in JavaScript](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Objects_in_JavaScript).

Comment: use json.sites.site[0].src ,json.sites.site[1].src

Comment: I get an XmlHTTPRequest Error. It apparently cannot parse a local file

Comment: @Dagrooms — Correct. Use HTTP if you want to use XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Is there a function specifically for parsing a local file? I don't necessarily "want" to use XMLHttpRequest, I am because that's what I found on this page.

Comment: No. Accessing local files is a security risk (e.g. an HTML document attached to an email and then opened in the browser is a local file) and most browsers block it.

Comment: There has to be some way to get the data from my local JSON file to my script. This can't just be impossible.

Comment: Why must it be possible to break past a security system? If it was, there wouldn't be any point in having the security system in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to parse the json. It will automatically parse the json since you are using  $.getJSON().

Comment: use json.sites.site[0].src ,json.sites.site[1].src

Comment: Now how I can put the value of name and src in an array? It's right to use $.each?

Comment: OK and how I can recognize if I'm reading "name" or "src" or "id" or "expiryDate"?
I made so `$.each(json, function(key, value) { });`

Comment: $.each(json.sites.site,function(index,value){ alert(value.src);})