# reading .json file into javascript JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am testing whether i could read a item in a .json file into javascript JSON object and display the contents. I need to store the BIDs in the variable R1 array and display it

Code is as follows

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<script type="application/javascript">
function loadJSON()
{
   var data_file = "data1.json";
   var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   try{
      // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari
      http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }catch (e){
      // Internet Explorer Browsers
      try{
         http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }catch (e) {
         try{
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
         }
      }
   }
   http_request.onreadystatechange  = function(){
      if (http_request.readyState == 4  )
      {
        // Javascript function JSON.parse to parse JSON data
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);


        var R1 = new Array();    

for(var i= 0 ; i< jsonObj.length; i++){
   R1.push(jsonObj[i].BID);
   document.write(R1);
}



      }
   }
   http_request.open("GET", data_file, true);
   http_request.send();
}




</script>

</body>
</html>
```

AND my data1.json is as follows

```
[ { "BID" : "4569749", }, { "BID" : "466759", }, { "BID" : "4561149", }, ]
```

Comment: Why do you tag the question with jQuery when you aren't using it?

Comment: what you want exactly

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse local JSON file with jQuery and Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944344/parse-local-json-file-with-jquery-and-javascript)

Comment: i could like to check whether the code written is correctly accepting the BIDs and display the contents of array R1 in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can load Json objects, As I did in one of my JSP project. here is the code so that you can easily understand.It is calling a servlet which prepare JSON file from the DB.

```
        $('document').ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST', 
                url: 'getCities',
                success: function(data) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(data);
                    var products = response['city'];
                    var product_html = '';
                    $(products).each(function(index, value){
                        product_html += ""+value['name']+"";
                    });
                    product_html += "";
                    $("#citylist").html(product_html);
                }
            }); 
        });
```

here 'getCities' is a servlet which prepare JSON file from Data fetched from Database. It is  actually populating the dropdownlist related to particular counties.

One more thing I believe the json file is incorrect. Please check the format with some json validator.