# How to parse a local JSON file from a locally browsed HTML page in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, html, local

I am looking for a way to parse a local **JSON** file from a none-hosted **HTML page** (*e.g.*: *`file:///C:/Folder/To/Your/HTML/default.html`*) without using AJAX since it will only entail an `allow access-origin` error.
I also cannot use **JSONP** since the HTML is not hosted to any hosting server (whether locally or remotely hosted).

Comment: can you use a file input?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading local json file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file)

Comment: Maybe you can load it in an iframe using the src attribute and parse the contents using innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

suppose your json file 'json.data' is like below:

```
data = '[{"name" : "Harry", "age" : "32"}]';
```

you have to load the json file into html head section like below:

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="file.json"></script>
```

and then in body section you have to call the javascript function to parse json data like..

```
<body onload="load();"></body>
```

javascript code:

```
<script>
function load() {
    var mydata = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(mydata[0].name);
    alert(mydata[0].age);
}
</script>
```

that's it.

Comment: you can also see this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944344/parse-local-json-file-with-jquery-and-javascript

Comment: you don't parse script files, and the code show simply won't work.